# TOP Asterisk DLL/Wrappers for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, voip, asterisk

I need to develop some CRM with phone functionality. We shall use Asterisk. I have found dll like Asterisk.NET but seams it is not supported. A PJLIB that has written in C++.  Can you recommend dll for it? Thanks.

**Found some:**
http://code.google.com/p/sipeksdk/

http://code.google.com/p/pjsip4net/

http://rtpmobile.sitesled.com/download.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have option to choose something other then Asterisk, then I will recommend you the FreeSwitch based [Plivo Framework](http://www.plivo.org/), which will provide you simple REST based APIs to integrate telephony services into your application.

Otherwise to build something upon Asterisk you should go with AMI ([Asterisk Manager Interface](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API)) and AGI ([Asterisk Gateway Interface](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI))